# How to share enum values in mongoose shema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, enums, mongoose

I have mongoose schema with the following enum values:

`kind: {
    type: Number,
    enum: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 11]
}`

And in some of my router I need to use one of these value like the following:

`Model.create({kind: 10}).exec(callback);`

The problem I'm faced with is using number `10` instead symbolic name. So what is the best way to share named constants and use bith in shema and routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define const for each `kind`, and use it in both: schema and router:

```
// consts.js
const KIND0 = 0;
const KIND1 = 1;
...
const KIND10 = 1;
const KINDS = [KIND0, KIND1,...,KIND10];

// schema.js
kind: {
  type: Number,
  enum: KINDS
}

// router.js
Model.create({ kind: KIND10 }).exec(callback);
```

Answer (score 4):

I like to attach them with the model:

```
const ENUM = {
  ONE: 1,
  TWO: 2,
  TEN: 10
};

const kindSchema = new Schema({
  kind: { type: Number, enum: _.values(ENUM) }
});

kindSchema.statics.KINDS = ENUM;

Model.create({ kind: Model.KINDS.TEN });
```